# Slack python bot make action to new messages in all channels from conversations_list()

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I have a python [slack-client](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient) app.

```
from slack import RTMClient

@RTMClient.run_on(event="message")
def say_hello(**payload):
  print('hello')

token = ''
rtm_client = RTMClient(token=token)
```

What I want it to do is to `print ('hello')` to every new message in every channel available by:

```
client = slack.WebClient(token=token)
channels = client.conversations_list()
```

However at the moment I am able to `print` only new messages in the channels my bot have joined. Is there a way to do so?